# Format problems in visual studio (.NET 5)

Tags: asp.net-core, formatting, .net-5

Currently i am developing my first .NET 5 MVC application. By now i have the Problem that the shortcut STRG+K - STRG+D makes a huge difference in formatting my html code with razor code. It looks like the following screenshot:

[image]

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following methods:

1. Use the `Ctrl + K` and `Ctrl + D` shortcut.

   Select all the `@if` code snippet, click the `Ctrl + K` shortcut, and then press the `Ctrl + D` shortcut.

   [image]
2. Use the Tab and `Shift + Tab` shortcut.

   `Tab`: Indents the currently selected line or lines by one tab stop. If there is no selection, this inserts a tab stop.
   `Shift + Tab`: Moves current line or selected lines one tab stop to the left.
   Select the code snippet, use the Tab and `Shift + Tab` shortcut to change the format.

   [image]
3. Use a Parent element.

   Put the `@if` code snippet in the `<div>` element, use the `Ctrl+X` shortcut to get the `</div>` end tag, and then use the `Ctrl+V` shortcut to add the `</div>` end tag. As we can see that, the `@if` statement will auto format.

   [image]

Comment: is there no possibility to make this automatically what you are doing in step 2 ? The old formatting function was way better thant the actual one.

Comment: Hi @LukasHieronimusAdler, I add a new method (add a parent tag for the `@if` statement), you could check it from the above reply.